# Camel type converter with dependency injection fails instantiation

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I have a TypeConverter class which is set up in a blueprint.xml file with an injected dependency via the constructor. I can verify that the class is created when deploying the OSGI bundle to FuseESB.

I apply the type converter using the `convertBodyTo` element in a camel context

```
<convertBodyTo type="com.example.RegisterRequest" />
```

but this fails with an instantiation exception when constructing the converter

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.RegisterRequestConverter
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:359)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)[:1.7.0_21]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.newInstance(ObjectHelper.java:1166)
```

If I add a noarg constructor then the converter is created - but obviously without it's dependency.

The Camel documentation for type converters http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html states that

> static methods are encouraged to reduce caching, but instance methods
>   are fine, particularly if you want to allow optional dependency
>   injection to customize the converter

Is it possible to define routes via xml and still have type converters dependency injected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible. A type converter should either be

- static method
- has a no-arg public constructor

And not use an IoC etc.

If you want IoC etc then you would need to register the instance manually into the Camel TypeConverterRegistry. This can be a bit cumbersome to do.

Comment: Am I right in assuming I'd have to do this in Java instead of via blueprint xml?